# catkin: generate_messages before building library?

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I specify in the CMakeList.txt the generation of messages and building of a library. I know how to generate messages only. But when I added a library that used these message the library was compiled before the messages had been generated.

So what is the correct way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55339/catkin:-generate_messages-before-building-library?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-15

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-15**:
Regardless of catkin or rosbuild, the recommended practice is to define messages in a separate package. That might or might not help with this problem.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-15**:
Yes, I usually do that. But for now I have a package were we have not split it that way. And that would have been a working solution if I had not found a working dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the answer:

```
add_dependencies(CUASVNodelets lrs_cvimage_gencpp)
```

solved my problem in the package lrs_cvimage. For me this is not intuitive at all that I have to specify a dependency inside the package. I mean messages could always be generated before compiling.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-15**:
This Q/A might help explain it: http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-15**:
catkin relies on native cmake for the build process, and thus add_dependencies is the only way to create a build order (other than wrapping cmake targets, which is against catkin philisophy).

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-02-16**:
Now when I have made this mistake I will probably start to think that it is natural to specify this dependency.  It was just a bit annoying that it was hard to find this information. i think this should be in the tutorials since that was what I checked first.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-17**:
Definitely. https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/issues/4